# Arch Linux boot messages show random ASCII characters

Tags: linux, boot, virtualbox, arch-linux

I'm new to Arch Linux, but I've studied some tutorials and read the  Arch Linux installation, getting started and beginner's guides.

I have installed a basic Arch Linux on a VirtualBox machine. The machine seems to run just fine and I'm very happy with that, however while booting, part of the boot messages is just random garbled text.

[image]

Should I worry about this? Where do these messages come from? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you've fixed this yet, but my solution was to make sure that I had a "vconsole.conf" file in /etc fixed this problem.  I was using the same setup and getting the same strange characters.